# uploadifive file size limit issue

Tags: uploadifive

I bought 'uploadifive' today. I managed to get it to work with firefox and opera. However, I can only upload small files. The filesizelimit or sizeLimit or uploadlimit option does not seem to work for me? Do I have to format it in a certain way, or maybe I have to change something in the uploadifive.php file too?

here is the index file below.  Any help would be great.  thanks : )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
            'auto'             : false,
            'checkScript'      : 'check-exists.php',
            'formData'         : {
                                   'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                                   'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                                 },
            'queueID'           : 'queue',
            'uploadLimit'        : 0,
                            'uploadScript'      : 'uploadifive.php',
            'onUploadComplete'  : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There's a `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_filesize` inside your php.ini file that you have to edit.

Comment: hello,there is no php.ini file with the latest uploadifive-v1.2.2-standard.zip $5 download.

Comment: @Joshua Terrill  thank you i found the php.ini for my localhost testing server 'wampserver' and changed both post_max_size and upload_max_size.  thanks again : )

Comment: No problem! Just remember that if you ever take this to a public server, the php ini file may be configured in a different directory, so just uploading your php ini file to the root may not make a difference. You'll have to find out where it's located on that specific server.

Comment: @user3434591 could you please give the values of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size you used? I still have the same problem. The uploader reaches 100% then start from 0% again.